# Sylius: how to notify payment if capture token is not in the url?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am creating my own payment bundle with Payum. I managed to correctly generate the payment order with my payment entity and my bundle redirects correctly to the payment page of my entity (where the user enters their card and PIN number). The problem is that I can not validate the payment. My payment entity only allows me to configure a single payment confirmation asynchronous call url (and it does not allow me to send a parameter with the notification url in each order).

How do I have to proceed to obtain the payment token? Is there any way to get the payment token from the order id and then validate it?

Comment: The payment system must have a page to call. Example with stripe when creating a load: https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges


The process of banking verification can be long (for the user) and must be done asynchronously.

Comment: @LeMenachFlorian Yes, the payment sistem have a page to call, but this page is unmutable and unique, so you don't have the token in the url. The only parameter usefull payment system sends me in asynchronously is payment_id... but i don't know how to get payment token with payment_id

Comment: Ok I understand better. I already made several implementations, especially with stripe and when creating the load, an identifier is given to me. This identifier is stored in database and serves as a comparison during validation.
Which payment system do you use? Is the card number entered on your site or on an external site?

Comment: We have https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-id and https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-status
For CB i use https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i think i've made it. This is the "solution":

First of all, i had to create an url for notifications with a controller atached.

```
payum_ceca_notification_url:
path: /payum/ceca/bank-notification
methods: [GET, POST]
defaults:
    _controller: CecaPlugin:Notify:do
```

Then in my doAction:

```
    public function doAction(Request $request):Response
    {
        $params = $request->request->all();
        $order_id = (int) $params['Num_operacion']; 

        $payment = $this->container->get('sylius.repository.payment')->findOneBy(['id' => $order_id]);

        $details = $payment->getDetails();
        $cecaOptions = array(
            'Environment' => $details['Environment'],
            'MerchantID' => $details['MerchantID'],
            'AcquirerBIN' => $details['AcquirerBIN'],
            'TerminalID' => $details['TerminalID'],
            'ClaveCifrado' => $details['ClaveCifrado']);
        $apiCeca = new ApiCeca($cecaOptions);
        $apiCeca->setFormHiddens(array(
            'Num_operacion' => $details['Num_operacion'],
            'Importe' => $details['Amount'],
            'URL_OK' => $details['url_ok'],
            'URL_NOK' => $details['url_nok'].'?pagocancelado=1'
        ));

        // check my sign vs the sign sent to me by payment entity 
        $apiCeca->checkTransaction($params);
        $payment->setState(PaymentInterface::STATE_COMPLETED);
        $payment->getOrder()->setPaymentState(OrderPaymentStates::STATE_PAID);
        $manager = $this->container->get('sylius.manager.payment');
        $manager->persist($payment);
        $manager->flush();

        return new Response();
    }
```

I know that it is not the most elegant solution but it is a solution that works, marks the order as paid.